# iferror returns #Name? instead of string

Tags: excel, vba, formula

IFERROR function returns "#NAME?" instead of string "National"

Below is the code.Please anyone help me out

`Range("AK2:AK" & ORCA_7point5_Count).FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IFERROR(IF(RC[-34]=VLOOKUP(RC[-34],'State;National'!C[-36],1,0),RC[-26]),"National")"`

Thanks in advance

Comment: mine is office 360 Pro. Daniel ans gave the solution. thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't validate your formula, but this would be a syntax error for a start because you missed quotation marks: `""National""`

Comment: thanks @daniel it solved the issue. Should use ""text""